# Duplicate Source Error on apt-get update

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie

*W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://packages.matrix.one/matrix-creator/ ./ Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/packages.matrix.one_matrix-creator_._Packages)* (9 times)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems

I tried "sudo apt-get upgrade" and "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" but it still doesn't works.
I also tried to remove the duplicate sources by:
"sudo awk '!a[$0]++' /etc/apt/sources.list"
"grep -R --include="*.list" chrome /etc/apt/"
However, it still doesn't work please help, thank you.

Comment: also did you try sudo apt-get **update**

Answer (score 1):

This should show you how many duplicates your have, then you can manually remove the lines.

```
$ sudo -s
$ cd /etc/apt/
$ grep -rl packages.matrix.one/matrix-creator/ .
```

look through your sources list and remove the duplicate lines (most likely 2 lines)

```
sudo -s
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```